# How to represent an indeterminate value in code?

Tags: javascript, state

I'm writing a component that will superimpose a badge over a given element, similar to the unread messages badge you would see on a mail app's icon. The badge can display a number, a single letter, or an **indeterminate state** which would indicate that the user should take note of the icon. The indeterminate state is similar to what Slack uses on their Mac app (first image):

[image: App icon with indeterminate state] [image: App icon with a "1" badge]

The value displayed by the badge is passed to the component with a settings object, for example:

```
myComponent({
    value: 2
});
```

**What should I ask the coders to assign to `value` to indicate that the state is indeterminate?**

Some options:

- `undefined` may indicate that the coder never assigned a value to the property at all (either they forgot, or they assigned the result of a function call that didn't return a proper value)
- An empty string has the same problems as `undefined`
- `null` is unique, but it feels wrong to display a badge when given a falsy value
- `false` has the same problem as `null`
- `true` could work, but it feels a little strange to re-purpose a Boolean for use as a literal value
- A special phrase like `"indeterminate"` or `"stateless"` would be hard to remember, could have typos, etc.

Any better ideas than `{value: true}`? What would *feel right* and/or be memorable?

Comment: This is you choice and depends on what you want to do. Just remember to add a comment to the code to indicate what it is and why.

Comment: I would use `-1`. As precedent, JavaScript that as a return value when searching an array for a string has failed.

Comment: This is opinion based really.  To throw another one in for you to think about - don't pass `{value: ? }` at all, instead use a different property, eg `{indeterminate: true}`.  That way you can expect `value` to always contain a proper value rather than it holding things that mean different things.

Comment: If you are using a code editor with decent autocomplete you can go with a "constant" holding the indeterminate value. Something like `var INDETERMINATE = <any_value>`. Using a constant will keep you code clean from magic numbers or null having a meaning. Even if you decide to set the const to be null you want be using null directly in your code. Just compare `if (value === -1)` or `if (value === null)` with `if (value === INDETERMINATE)`. It will be hard to remember what the first 2 do after a year.